# Distance between closed convex sets made with cones

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A: X\to X$ be a bounded linear operator in the Banach space $X$. Given vectors $a_1,\dots,a_m;\,b_1,\dots,b_n;\,p,q\in X$, consider cones  $P=\{\alpha_1 a_1+\dots\alpha_m a_m:\alpha_i\ge0, i=1,\dots,m\}$ and $Q=\{\alpha_1 b_1+\dots\alpha_n b_n:\alpha_i\ge0, i=1,\dots,n\}$. Put $M=A^{-1}(p+P)$ and $N=A^{-1}(q+Q)$. Assuming $M\cap N=\emptyset$, can we show that $$d(M,N)=\inf\{||x-y||:x\in M,y\in N\}>0?$$

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then yes, the distance is positive. but I'm not sure about case where the kernel of $A$ is nonzero space

Comment: If you could write down your thoughts on the problem, that would help others to help you better.

Comment: May I know where have you encountered with this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is continuous it follows
$$
dist(AM,AN) \le \|A\| dist(M,N).
$$
In addition, $AM\subset p+P$, $AN\subset q+Q$.
Then $dist(M,N)=0$ implies $dist(AM,AN)\ge dist(p+P,q+Q)=0$. The cone $P-Q$ is generated by non-negative linear combinations of a finite number of vectors, it is closed (see this reference: http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/Opt/farkas.pdf ) . Then if
$dist(p+P,q+Q)=dist(p-q,-P+Q)=0$ if follows $p-q \in -P+Q$, hence $(p+P)\cap (q+Q)\ne\emptyset$, hence $M\cap N\ne\emptyset$.

This proves that $M\cap N=\emptyset$ implies $dist(M,N)>0$.

Comment: 2.  $d(p+P,q+Q)=\inf\{||(p+x)-(q+y)||:x\in P,y\in Q\}

 =\inf\{||(p-q)-(y-x)||:x\in P,y\in Q\} =d(p-q,Q-P)$

Comment: Yes 2 is fine  but  I am not sure about 1,  1-Why do we have 
dist(AM,AN)=dist(p+P,q+Q)

For example what if $A=0$

@Math253

Comment: Yes, the equality should be the weak inequality $\ge$, though we still have $d(p+P,q+Q)=0$.

Comment: @Math253  you take $X= \Bbb R$, $A=0$, $P=Q=\{0\} $ and $p=1$ and $q=2$ then we have $d(AM,AN) =0$ but $d(p+P,q+Q) = 1 >0$

Comment: @Ashkan in this case $AM=AN=\emptyset$ and $d(AM,AN)=+\infty$. I edited the answer, please check. thanks for your comments

Comment: @Math253 edited the asnwer, please check. Thanks for your comments